# Counting items in a PHP array_chunk

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have the below function which gets wordpress posts and outputs them in a bootstrap grid (3 posts per row). Each array chunk has 3 posts in it. Basically what I want to do is if the chunk is not complete and only has say 2 posts in it then the first post in that chunk gets "col-sm-offset-2" class added. I believe I need some way off counting the posts in the chunk but I'm not sure how to implement.

```
    function post_events($atts) {

    global $post;

    $args = array(
    'post_type'    => 'event',
    'post_status'  => 'publish',
    'orderby'      => 'date',
    'order'        => 'ASC',
    );

    $posts = get_posts($args);

    $posts_chunks = array_chunk($posts, 3);

    $output = '';

    foreach ($posts_chunks as $row) {

        $output .= '<div class="row">';

        foreach ($row as $post) {

            setup_postdata($post);

            $output .= '<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 event-item">';
            $output .= '<a href="' .get_the_permalink(). '">' .get_the_post_thumbnail(). '</a>';
            $output .= '<div class="event-item-text">';
            $output .= '<h3><a href="'.get_the_permalink(). '">' .get_the_title(). '</a></h3>';
            $output .= '<span class="event-date">' .get_the_date("d-m-Y"). '</span>';
            $output .= '<p>' .wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 40, '...' ). '</p>';
            $output .= '</div>';
            $output .= '</div>';
        }

        $output .= '</div>';
    }

    return $output;
 }

add_shortcode('post_events','post_events');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have chunked, the subarrays will be `0` based and the first post will be `0`.  So just check that and if the `count` is less than `3`:

```
foreach ($posts_chunks as $row) {

    $output .= '<div class="row">';

    foreach ($row as $key => $post) {
        $extra = '';  //set extra class to empty
        if($key == 0 && count($row) < 3) { //check first post and count less than 3
            $extra = 'col-sm-offset-2 '; //set extra class
        }
        setup_postdata($post);
        //use $extra somewhere
        $output .= '<div class="'.$extra.'col-md-6 col-sm-6 event-item">';
        $output .= '<a href="' .get_the_permalink(). '">' .get_the_post_thumbnail(). '</a>';
        $output .= '<div class="event-item-text">';
        $output .= '<h3><a href="'.get_the_permalink(). '">' .get_the_title(). '</a></h3>';
        $output .= '<span class="event-date">' .get_the_date("d-m-Y"). '</span>';
        $output .= '<p>' .wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 40, '...' ). '</p>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '</div>';
    }

    $output .= '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) on `$row`, and then set the class based on whether it's the first iteration or not:

```
$class = 'col-md-6 col-sm-6 event-item';
$count = count($row);

foreach( $row as $k => $post ) 
{
    $cls = ($k == 0 && $count < 2) ? $class.' col-sm-offset-2' : $class;
    setup_postdata($post);
    $output.= '<div class="'.$cls.'">';
    //...
}
```